# pass parameter to getters in Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a Vue component like this:

```
<script>
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  props: ['index'],
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      'type',
      'width',
      'height',
      'description',
      'smtTagMeasureUnits',
      'tagValue'
    ])
  }
</script>

<template>
  <div :class='["block","module-"+type(index), "width"+width(index), "height"+height(index)]'>
    <h3>{{ description(index) }}</h3>
    <div class="data">
      <h1>{{ tagValue(index) }}</h1>
      <h2 class="measure">{{ smtTagMeasureUnits(index) }}</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
  ...
</style>
```

Parameter ***index***, which comes into component as a *prop*, has been successfully passed to getters:

```
getters: {
  ...
  type: (state, getters) => (par) => {
    return getters.widgetsConfig[par].type
  },
  width: (state, getters) => (par) => {
    if (getters.widgetsConfig[par].width) {
      return getters.widgetsConfig[par].width
    } return 2
  },
  height: (state, getters) => (par) => {
    if (getters.widgetsConfig[par].height) {
      return getters.widgetsConfig[par].height
    } return 1
  },
  ...
}
```

Works fine, but i'm not happy with this codestyle, because `getterName(index)` constantly repeats in the template part. All of my getters should carry *index* as a prop, so i'd like to have just `getterName` in the template and something like this in the script part:

```
...mapGetters([
'type',
'width',
'height',
'description',
'smtTagMeasureUnits',
'tagValue'
], index)
```

Is it possible to achieve any codestyle improvements here?

Answer (score 17):

If you want to keep things DRY, it would make sense to leverage logic of getting item (entity that `index` corresponds to) information to the store, so component only receives full data that is ready to be rendered.

Suggested solution is to create a single getter, that accepts `index` as an argument and returns full list of options from `getters.widgetsConfig`.

*Note that if needed other getters may be re-used in order to collect necessary information into a single object.*

Possible implementation:

```
getters: {
  ...
  getItemByIndex: (state, getters) => (index) => {
    const { type, height, width } = getters.widgetsConfig[index]
    return {
      type,
      height,
      width
    }
  },
}
```

And update component to map a single getter and use it in computed property:

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters([
    'getItemByIndex'
  ]),
  item () {
    return this.getItemByIndex(index)
  }
}
```

And all properties will be accessible inside a template via `item.type`, `item.height`, `item.width`, etc..

Comment: Incredible solution, thank you. I was not looking for this problem, but found this question and could not imagine that would be possible to do that. lol

Answer (score 7):

You can always make computed properties that return the result of the getters. Something like:

```
export default {
  props: ['index'],
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      'getTypeFromIndex',
      'getWidthFromIndex',
      'getHeightFromIndex'
    ]),
    height(): { return this.getHeightFromIndex(index) },
    width(): { return this.getWidthFromIndex(index) },
    type(): { return this.getTypeFromIndex(index) },

    //going a step further to clean up your templates...
    classList: [
        "block", 
        "height"+this.height,
        "width"+this.width,
    ]
  }
```

That way you just need `height` in your templates instead of `height(index)`, or even just `classList` if you take it that far

This is also referenced here: https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/688 and I can't find it but I know I've seen that recommended by Evan You in a github issue as well.